# Gauss-Seidel method convergence algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method#Convergence):

> The convergence properties of the Gauss–Seidel method 
>       are dependent on the matrix A. Namely, the procedure 
>       is known to converge if either:
>
> ```
> 1. A is symmetric positive-definite, or
> 2. A is strictly or irreducibly diagonally dominant.
> ```

Is there algorithm for transforming matrix to meet the convergence criteria or must I do it manually?

I am implementing Gauss-Seidel method in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int n;
double eps = 0.001;

//yygnanma sherti
bool converge(double *xk, double *xkp)
{
    double norm = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
      norm += (xk[i] - xkp[i])*(xk[i] - xkp[i]);
    }
    if(sqrt(norm) >= eps)
      return false;
    return true;
}


int main()
{
    //olcheg
    printf("Olchegi giriz: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    //koeffisientler uchin
    double a[n][n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            double tmp;
            printf("a[%d][%d] = ", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%lf", &tmp);
            a[i][j] = tmp;
        }
    }

    //azat agzalar uchin
    double b[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        double tmp;
        printf("b[%d] = ", i+1);
        scanf("%lf", &tmp);
        b[i] = tmp;
    }

    double x[n];
    double p[n];

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        x[i] = 0;
        p[i] = 0;
    }

    do
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            p[i] = x[i];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            double var = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                var += (a[i][j] * x[j]);
            for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
                var += (a[i][j] * p[j]);
            x[i] = (b[i] - var) / a[i][i];
        }
    }while (!converge(x, p));

    return 0;
}
```

Now I want to implement matrix transformation algorithm (if there is one) to meet convergence criteria.

Comment: Where does your matrix A come from? Is it symmetric? Clearly arbitrarily "transforming" the matrix to meet some criteria may change the problem you are solving -- so if you tell me more about the problem I can make some suggestions.

Comment: A is not symmetric matrix. I am going to implement for abitrary matrix

Comment: @torayeff you left out the fact that it will often converge without those conditions. Usually, if the system was small I would manually work it till there was as much diagonal dominance as possible.

Comment: Why are you implementing this algorithm for a dense matrix?

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution for my question and implemented it in C++:

```
/*
 * www.twitter.com/torayeff
 * 
 * Gauss-Seidel method:
 * http://math.semestr.ru/optim/methodzeidel.php
 * http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss–Seidel_method
 * http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Метод_Гаусса_—_Зейделя
 * 
 * To solve A*x = b transform to 
 * A(t)*A*x = A(t)*b <---> C*x = d 
 * (A(t) transpose of matrix A)
 * (in this state, Gauss-Seidel method always congerges)
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

#define MAXN 100

int N; //matrix dimension
double eps = 0.001;
double err = eps;
double A[MAXN][MAXN];
double b[MAXN][MAXN];
double At[MAXN][MAXN];
double C[MAXN][MAXN];
double d[MAXN][MAXN];

//convergence check
bool converge(double *xk, double *xkp)
{
    double norm = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) 
    {
      norm += (xk[i] - xkp[i])*(xk[i] - xkp[i]);
    }
    if(sqrt(norm)>=eps)
      return false;
    err = eps;
    return true;
}


int main()
{
    printf("Input dimension N: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            double tmp;
            printf("A[%d][%d] = ", i+1, j+1);
            scanf("%lf", &tmp);
            A[i][j] = tmp;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        double tmp;
        printf("b[%d] = ", i+1);
        scanf("%lf", &tmp);
        b[i][0] = tmp;
    }


    //transpose A
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            At[i][j] = A[j][i];
        }
    }

    //multiply At*A = C
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            C[i][j] = 0;
            for(int k=0; k<N; k++)
            {
                C[i][j] = C[i][j] + At[i][k]*A[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    //multiply At*b = d
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<1; j++)
        {
            d[i][j] = 0;
            for(int k=0; k<N; k++)
            {
                d[i][j] = d[i][j] + At[i][k]*b[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    //Solve Gauss-Seidel method for C*x = d
    double x[N]; //current values
    double p[N]; //previous values

    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        x[i] = 0;
        p[i] = 0;
    }

    do
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
            p[i] = x[i];

        for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            double v = 0.0;
            for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
            {
                double cij;
                if(i==j) cij = 0;
                else cij = -1.0*C[i][j]/C[i][i];
                v += cij*x[j];
            }

            for(int j=i; j<N; j++)
            {
                double cij;
                if(i==j) cij = 0;
                else cij = -1.0*C[i][j]/C[i][i];
                v += cij*p[j];
            }
            v +=  1.0*d[i][0]/C[i][i];
            x[i] = v;
        }

    }while (!converge(x, p));

    //print solution
    printf("Err. val.: %lf\n", err);
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("%lf ", x[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```